# Russian classic literature with stress markings

Tags: литература, ударение

I am a Polish native speaker. I have a pretty good passive understanding of written Russian. I have however a terrible pronunciation, especially with regards to stress (it always falls on the penultimate syllable in Polish). I believe I could improve it by reading texts that have stress markings.

Are there any editions of classic Russian literature that feature stress markings? Both paper and electronic editions would interest me.

Answer (score 7):

I want to propose you a better solution of the problem http://morpher.ru/accentizer/ - this program makes stress marks in every Russian text. Or Google: Тексты с ударениями 
For example [https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/Толстый_и_тонкий_(Чехов,_текст_с_ударениями)](https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B8_%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_(%D0%A7%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B2,_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82_%D1%81_%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8))

Comment: That first link just handles a few paragraphs at a time, not a whole book, right?

Answer (score 3):

You should look for books labeled "Russian for foreigners" (Русский язык для иностранцев). They are available for sale quite cheaply, for instance, at [litres.ru](http://www.litres.ru/pages/biblio_search/?q=%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B2). Not all of them have stresses marked, but after registration you may preview samples and see for yourself. Audiobooks are there as well.